# Getting StateError (Bad state: Too many elements) while streaming in Dart/Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, stream, stream-builder

I'm using Multiprovider to provide my custom GameLobby class like that:

```
var game_lobby = GameLobby(user: user);
  return MultiProvider(
    providers: [
      StreamProvider<GameState>(create: (_) => game_lobby.gameStateStream,),
      Provider<GameLobby>(create: (_) => game_lobby,),
    ],
    child: GameRoomScreen()
  );
```

Later, in GameLobby class I made a call to firebase.firestore to create a new collection

```
await gameRef.doc(user.uid).set({
    'lobbyName': 'Lobimiz',
    'code' : generateNewRoomCode(),
    'date': Timestamp.now(),
    'players' : [user.uid]
  })
  .then((value) => {
    gameRef.doc(user.uid).snapshots().listen((event) {
      
      Map<String, dynamic> firestoreInfo = event.data();
      
      players = [...firestoreInfo['players']];
      print(event.data().toString());
      gameState = GameState.InLobby; /* GAMESTATE SETTER IS CALLED */

    })
  })
  // ignore: missing_return
  .onError((error, stackTrace) {print(error.toString());});
```

This code usually works for the 1st time. When I manually insert an entry on firebase for testing purpose,
gameRef.doc(user.uid).snapshots().listen() is triggered again since entry is changed and I'm listening to it.

This time gameState attribute is change and gameState is streamed in  setter method like:

```
set gameState(GameState state){
    this._gameState = state;
    this._streamController.sink.add(this._gameState);
  }
```

I wanted to add new gameState to stream and rebuild something according to new state and playerlist. But now I'm getting

StateError (Bad state: Too many elements)

Which is defined and throwned as in here:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Stream/single.html

> // This is the second element we get.
>
> try {   throw
>
> IterableElementError.tooMany();

What is the problem here? Doesn't streams allow more than one sink element at a time?

Answer (score 2):

`Stream.single` is the async equivalent of `List.single`, which takes a `List` and returns the one and only element in the list:

```dart
['hello'].single  // returns the String 'hello'
['hello', 'world'].single  // throws StateError
[].single  // also throws StateError
```

`Stream.single` behaves similarly: if you call it on a stream with no elements, it throws, and if you call it on a stream with 2 or more elements, it also throws.

You don't include the code that actually calls `single`, so it's hard to know what you're using it for, but a common mistake is to think that `single` gives you the "current value" of the `Stream`.

Unfortunately, Dart `Stream`s don't really have a "current value". You have a couple of options if this is what you're after:

1. Use a `StreamBuilder`:

```dart
StreamBuilder(
  stream: stream,  // make sure you create this outside build(), e.g. in initState()
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    // snapshot.data gives you the "current value"
  }
)
```

2. If you want to do a similar thing in a flutter-independent way, you can use the `rxdart` package and teh `BehaviorSubject` class:

```
BehaviorSubject subject = streamData();  // a special type of stream provided by rxdart 
await doSomeAsyncStuff();
subject.value  // the last value added to this subject, or throws if nothing was added
```

Comment: Hi. I didn't use Stream.single anywhere, not aware of that method exist. I couldn't find any clue about the exception, so I changed my code to use rxdart, take care of immutablety. Now it looks like working, I will inform if it happens again. Thank you

Comment: *@cameron1024* I got frequently this type of error on BehaviorSubject can you give me clue about this exception https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxdart/issues/667